# Зайти на сайт, выбрать checkbox и отправить форму

Tags: curl, php

Нужно зайти на сайт, отметить checkbox и отправить форму нажатием кнопки. Как такое на PHP реализовать?

Comment: Знаю, но не скажу, пока не узнаю, зачем.

Comment: @Fike нужно авторизовываться на одном сайте, логин пароль по GET-запросу поступают, а галочку и форму отправки как сделать не знаю.

Comment: @Fike ну и как же??

Comment: Не, то что надо заполнить какую-то форму, я сразу понял. Меня интересуют конечные цели.

Comment: @Fike а смысл? Авторизацию провожу, а затем парсинг данных.

Comment: Короче, мы тут не приветствуем спам, ботоводство и накрутки, а вопрос в такой постановке похож именно на это. Особенно учитывая что каждый вменяемый и раскрутившийся сервис стремится предоставить апи и third-party авторизацию.  
Из-за этого я и хочу быть уверенным в конечных целях.

Comment: @Fike это вообще не сервис, это система внутренняя. Сервак на C# написан, знаний для написания API на нем нет, поэтому пишу его на PHP.
Если не знаете как, то так и скажите.

Comment: @Lektor, хорошо, я неуч и не знаю

Comment: [Читаем гугл][1] и учимся.


  [1]: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=php+curl+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B&oq=%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B7+%D1%81%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%B4+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.8255j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: чукча не читатель, чукча писатель (ц) народная мудрость :)

Answer (score 1):

Lektor читайте про CURL в общем виде что вам надо передать параметры прямо в запросе